# Querying delegations for a validator at a specific height

Tags: tendermint, cosmos-sdk

Is it possible to query:

1. the set of delegators for a given validator at a specific height?
2. the amount each delegator has delegated to a given validator at a specific height?

Something like the output of the `/staking/delegators/{delegatorAddr}/delegations` RPC endpoint, but at a specific height.

I think it might be possible via `/abci_query`, but not sure on the `path` and `data` arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sounds like you want `/staking/validators/{validatorAddr}/delegations`, no?

https://cosmos.network/rpc/v0.37.9

to get a specific height, add a query param `?height=39000`

Comment: TIL that you can just add `?height=`!!! One downside is that this endpoint takes ~60 seconds to complete.